# Connection between the Riesz representation theorem and the double dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

My very tentative idea of the Riesz's representation theorem is that for all functionals in $V^*$ (dual space), $\phi\in V^*$, there exists a unique vector $v\in V$ such that for any other vector $u \in V$, $\phi(u)=\langle u,v\rangle$.

The definition of double vector space involves a mapping from the dual space functionals to the field, $\phi_v\colon V^* \to \mathbb F$, given by $\phi_v(f) = f(v)$.

So the $\forall u\in V$ part is missing in Riesz's representation, but the connection to the dual space in both definitions, and the *unique* part (isomorphism(?)) make it difficult to avoid comparisons. The problem is that I'm not getting good results when searching for answers.

For example, there is a hint of it in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1097289/152225), but I'm not familiar with Hilbert spaces.

Comment: The idea is more general: if $X$ is a Banach space, then $X$ always injects into the bidual $X^{**}$ via the map $x\mapsto \phi_x$ where $\phi_x(f)=f(x)$. This map is an isometry, so one may regard $X$ as a subspace of $X^{**}$. If the map is surjective then $X$ is said to be reflexive and the spaces are essentially the same.

Comment: @Chilango I am not following. Could you dispel the basic underlying doubt as to whether I am dealing with equivalent definitions of $V^{**}$?

Comment: The point is that the evaluation functionals $\phi_x$ may not account for all the functionals in $X^{**}$. This is only true if $X$ is reflexive. Now Hilbert spaces $are$ reflexive so the definitions agree, but this is not true in general.

Comment: Start off with finite-dimensional spaces, they're simpler than hilbert spaces which are their infinite-dimensional generalisations; first choose a basis and then go on from there to prove your statement in your first paragraph.

Comment: In the finite-dimensional case every linear functional is actually a *continuous* linear functional; this is not the case in infinite dimensions - which is why they at first restrict to what is called the *continuous* dual, in contra-distinction to the merely *linear* dual.